# Olympic Diving: how is the difficulty of a dive decided?

Tags: rules, olympics, scoring, diving

Shi Tingmao's fourth dive in the 2016 Rio Olympic 3m final was "Forward 3½ Somersaults" with a difficulty coefficient of 3.1.

How are such values determined?

In general, is the difficulty coefficient fixed or variable over time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values come from the [FINA Table of Degrees of Difficulty](http://www.fina.org/content/appendix-2-fina-table-degrees-difficulty-springboard)*

The tables are a matrix that combine the direction and number of any spins and twists, with the shape that is held during the dive.

[image]

As you can see, a Forward 3½ Somersault combined with a Pike results in a 3.1 difficulty coefficient.

<sub>* The link provided is for the 1m and 3m springboards. For 5m, 7.5m and 10m platform diving [see here](http://www.fina.org/content/appendix-4-fina-table-degrees-difficulty-platform)</sub>

Comment: Up for you. [Here](http://http://www.fina.org/content/appendix-1-fina-degree-difficulty-formula-and-components-springboard) is it possible to view the matrix quoted in ImClary answer